# Pause jQuery progress bar if tab or browser changed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, progress-bar

I have a progress bar that runs after 3 seconds when the window is loaded for a certain amount of time. It keeps running even if the user changes the tab or opens a new browser. I want to pause it if the user changes tab or browser and resume it when the tab becomes active.

This is my current code affecting jQuery progress bar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(".wait").hide();
                $("#progressTimer").progressTimer({
                    timeLimit: <?php echo $adf['ac_time']; ?>,
                    onFinish: function(){
                        $('#progressTimer').fadeOut(1000);
                        $("#captcha").fadeIn(3000);
                    }
                });
            }, 3000);
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### to pause and start progress bar on tab change:

```
$(window).blur(function(e) {
    // apply logic to pause
});
$(window).focus(function(e) {
    //apply logic to resume or start the progress bar
});
```

Comment: Could you please add the logic, how to start or pause/resume the progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit the plugin for this behaviour to take effect as the plugin [internally](https://github.com/tnory56/jquery-progressTimer/blob/master/dist/js/jquery.progresstimer.js#L98) uses setInterval and clearInterval which will have to be replaced with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and [cancelAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame) respectively.

Since the plugin uses setInterval the animation will not stop when the user switchs tabs , with requestAnimationFrame though when the user switches tabs , the animation will stop !

Comment: after changing those in my script now its not working.. bar is there but its not progressing now..

Comment: @AppleBux can you make a JS fiddle of your issue , so it can be debugged --> https://jsfiddle.net/